# Inward/Outward-pointing tangent vector is well-defined

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary and $p\in \partial M$. We say a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$ is *inward-pointing* if in a chart $x$ with $v=v^i\partial/\partial x^i$ (using the summation convention) one has $v^1>0$.

Why is this well-defined?

I.e. if $y$ is another chart around $p$ with $v=w^j \partial/\partial y^j$, how can we conclude that $w^1>0$?

I tried looking at the change of coordinates formula which says that $$w^1=\frac{\partial (y^1\circ x^{-1})}{\partial x^i}(x(p))v^i$$ but why should that be positive when $v^1>0$?

What am I missing?

Comment: Does your convention for charts at the boundary assume $x^{1} = 0$ on the boundary of $M$ and $x^{1} > 0$ in the interior?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, $x^1=0$ on the boundary of $M$ and the interior was defined as $M\setminus \partial M$, so yes, $x^1>0$ in the interior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$Near a boundary point, $M$ is modeled by the closed half-space $H = \{(x^{1}, \dots, x^{n} : x^{1} \geq 0\}$. Geometrically, a diffeomorphism representing a change of coordinates near a boundary point $p$ must preserve $H$, and so preserves the notion of a vector pointing toward the interior.

Analytically, if $v = v^{i} \dd_{i}$ is an inward-pointing tangent vector at some boundary point $p$, then the curve $\gamma(t) = p + tv$ lies in the *open* half-space $H^{0}$ for $t > 0$. If
$$
y^{j} = \phi^{j}(x) = \phi^{j}(x^{1}, x^{2}, \dots, x^{n})
$$
is a change of coordinates at $p$, then $y^{1} \geq 0$ and $\phi \circ \gamma$ is a curve in $H$ whose initial velocity
$$
w = (\phi \circ \gamma)'(0) = D\phi(p)\, v
  = \frac{\partial \phi^{j}}{\partial x^{i}}(p)\, v^{i}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y^{j}}
$$
points toward $H^{0}$, i.e.,
$$
w^{1} = \frac{\partial \phi^{1}}{\partial x^{i}}(p)\, v^{i} > 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though I am not sure I understand everything. Why must the initial velocity of $\phi\circ \gamma$ point toward $H^O$?

Comment: The first component $w^{1}$ can't be $0$ because $D\phi(p)$ is an isomorphism and the last $(n-1)$ columns of $D\phi(p)$ span the tangent space to the boundary, and $w^{1}$ can't be negative because $\phi\circ\gamma(t)$ is in $H^{0}$ for $t > 0$. (If it helps, consider a self-diffeomorphism $\phi$ of $[0, \infty)$: You have to have $\phi'(0) > 0$ for analogous reasons.)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I am still not sure I follow the details however. Let me ask you this question: Say we have two charts $x$ and $y$ around a point $p\in \partial M$. Then the change of coordinates, $x\circ y^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism, so its differential at $p$ is an isomorphism of $\Bbb R^n$. I already know it preserves points of the form $(0,a_2,\cdots, a_n)$. But I still do not see why points with positive first coordinate must necessarily map to points with positive first coordinate.

Comment: Why can't it map to a point with negative first coordinate? I would really appreciate if you could make this clear to me (sorry that I don't understand this...I am not very smart)

Comment: A change of coordinates at a boundary point preserves the half space $\{x^{1} \geq 0\}$; that is, in every coordinate chart the first coordinate in non-negative. :)

Comment: Right, that's plausible, but I still fail to see why that is so. :(

Comment: Somewhere in your definition of manifold-with-boundary there must be a stipulation about charts near a boundary point. This should easily imply (if it doesn't outright assume) that change of coordinates at a boundary point preserves the closed half space on which $M$ is modeled. If not, could you please add your definition of manifold-with-boundary to the question?

Comment: I understand it now, thanks for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome. :)